Find the Previous Date or Second-to-the-Last Date in a Filtered List
Sample Sheet Screenshot:

I'm building a worksheet where the previous payment date is automatically displayed, if there is any, based on the current payment date.
Conditions

The resulting date (Column L) must be earlier than the current payment date (Column H).

The resulting date (Column L) are pulled from the list of dates in Column H.

The resulting date came from a filtered list dates based on Customer Name (Column A) and Invoice No (Column B).

Customers can make multiple payments on the same date.


I have formula that works:
=INDEX(IFNA(FILTER($H$3:$H,($A$3:$A=A3)*($B$3:$B=B3)*($H$3:$H<H3)),),COUNT(FILTER($H$3:$H,($A$3:$A=A3)*($B$3:$B=B3)*($H$3:$H<H3))))
Another version of this formula:
=IFNA(QUERY($A$3:$H,"SELECT MAX(H) WHERE A = '"&$A$3:$A&"' AND B = '"&$B$3:$B&"' AND H < date '"&TEXT($H$3:$H,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' GROUP BY B LABEL MAX(H)''",0),)
This is placed on Cell L3. However, I must drag this formula down to apply to each row. If new rows are added, the formula no longer applies. Is there a way that we can make this formula work for the entirety of Column L?
The formula will check the Customer Name and Invoice No, pulls up a list of dates from Column H, and find the second to the last available date. If there is no date available, return blank.
I tried using VLOOKUP and XLOOKUP to combine with ARRAYFORMULA. I also tried using QUERY with INDEX and MATCH, but they don't seem to work with ARRAYFORMULA. Please help!

If your current formula works the you can make it dynamic array formula by using MAP() function. Try-
=MAP(A3:A,B3:B,H3:H,LAMBDA(x,y,z,IF(x="","",INDEX(IFNA(FILTER($H$3:$H,($A$3:$A=x)*($B$3:$B=y)*($H$3:$H<z)),),COUNT(FILTER($H$3:$H,($A$3:$A=x)*($B$3:$B=y)*($H$3:$H<z)))))))
Here is documentation from google support for MAP() function.
